# Game speed above faster

Tags: starcraft-2

Is it possible to somehow increase the game speed above Faster for training purposes? Are there any custom maps or modes available that can do this?

Answer (score 2):

From [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/starcraft/comments/52o15t/is_there_a_way_to_play_speed_up_starcraft_2/):

```
2.0X Game Speed 
battlenet:://starcraft/map/2/158301
125% game speed v 1.3 
battlenet:://starcraft/map/2/159410
```

So yes, there are such mods already. Have fun :)

Answer (score 0):

There are no ways to adjust the game speed past the "faster" setting. Game speed settings are a standard set by the engine itself, so it must be set to one of the 5 preset options (slower, slow, normal, fast, or faster) and must be configured before beginning a custom game.

However, user-created custom games can modify unit movement speeds, attack speeds, and build times in order to create the illusion of a more faster game type, but no such custom game exists to my knowledge.